# "$X$ and $Y$ have the same mean"$\implies$ "$P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)$"

Tags: probability, means

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Is the following true under certain conditions?

"$X$ and $Y$ have the same mean"$\implies$ "$P(X>Y)=P(X<Y)$".

Intuitively I think this is true in lots of cases. But I don't know what conditions are needed. For example, should $X$ and $Y$ be both discrete (or continuous)?

Comment: At least $X,Y$ must be defined on the same probability space. Else $X<Y$ makes no sense. But if so then still having the same mean is actually a rather weak condition.

Comment: It isn't true in general, for example let $X$ be the result of a six sided die with the normal sides $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $Y$ be the result of a six sided die with the sides $0,0,0,0,0,21$.  They have the same mean, but $P(X>Y)=\frac{5}{6}\neq \frac{1}{6}=P(X<Y)$

Comment: Suppose both distributions are symmetrical about the same mean?

Comment: @almagest even that won't do.  Take for instance a normal six-sided die.  Let $X$ be the result of the die modulo $6$.  Let $Y$ be the result of the die minus $1$ modulo $6$.  For instance, rolling a $3$ you have $x=3$ and $y=2$ while rolling a $6$ you have $x=0$ and $y=5$.  Here, $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, have the same mean, and are symmetrical, yet $Pr(X>Y)=\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, but in that case $X,Y$ are far from independent, whereas your previous example worked even if they were independent. Your comments essentially answer the Q. Do you want to convert them to that, or would you like me to write them up as a Community answer?