# If $E(X) = E(Y)$, do we have $P(X<Y) = P(X > Y)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

*Let X and Y be two real-valued random variables. Assume that X and Y are independent and that
$$E(X) = E(Y)$$
Then, is it true that $P(X<Y) = P(X > Y)$ ?*

So far, I have made a simulation using a computer program, and the assertion seems true.

To prove the assertion, I have thought about using the transfer formula but I can't find how to "link" expectation and probability (maybe one can use Markow's inequality).

EDIT : now I am aware that it is not true in the general case. But if one adds the hypothese that X and Y have both a symmetrical distribution with respect to their mean (i.e. $P(X < E(X)) = P(X > E(X))$), is the assertion true then ?

Comment: A simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Do you recognize that you have written  Y > X and X < Y , I.e. the same thing? Please clarify :)

Comment: Thanks. I will edit the Title and the question

Comment: Try $X \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ and $Y \sim\mathcal{N}(1,1)$ in your simulation.  Then $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y]$ but $\mathbb  P(X <Y)  > \mathbb  P(X >Y)$.  But if  $X$ and $Y$ are independently and identically distributed then you get equality by exchangeability

Comment: Yes you're right. Funnily, before your comment, I had simulated a sample $X∼Exp(2)$and $Y \sim\mathcal{N}(1/2,2)$ (I don't know why I pick a standard deviation of 2) and in this case $P(X<Y) \approx P(X>Y)$. I guess if I had carried a statistical test, I would have concluded that the probabilities were the same

Comment: I would NOT have concluded that the probabilities were the same

Comment: If we add the hypotheses that X and Y have a symmetrical distribution, then is it true ?

Comment: @Jan Van Impe, you can't just change the question as you go along invalidating the given answers. Accept the answer to your original question and ask another question separately.

Comment: I have just found that there is a similar question already https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3376742/556298

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true. For example, $X$ takes values $0$, $-1$ or $4$, each with probability $1/3$ and $Y=1$.

Comment: OK for your counter-example. Then if we assume in addition that X and Y are continuous, is the statement true ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be given by PDF $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\lambda e^{-\lambda (x+a)},& x\geq -a,\\ 0, & x < -a,\end{cases}$$

and let $Y$ be given by PDF $$g(y) = \begin{cases}\mu e^{-\mu (y+b)},& y\geq -b,\\ 0, & y < -b,\end{cases}$$

These are just shifted exponential distributions and \begin{align}E(X) &= \int_{-a}^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda (x+a)}dx = \int_0^\infty (x-a)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = \int_0^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx - a\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx\\ &= \frac 1\lambda - a.\end{align}
Similarly, $E(Y) = \frac 1\mu - b$. Then, choose $a = \frac 1 \lambda$ and $b = \frac 1\mu$ for the shifts to get the expected values $E(X) = E(Y) =0$

Finally, assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $0 \leq z := 1/\lambda - 1/\mu$
\begin{align}P(X<Y) &= \iint_{x<y}\lambda e^{-\lambda(x+1/\lambda)}\mu e^{-\mu(y+1/\mu)}\mathbb 1_{\{x \geq -1/\lambda\}}\mathbb 1_{\{y \geq -1/\mu\}}dxdy \\
&=\iint_{u - 1/\lambda< v - 1/\mu}\lambda e^{-\lambda u}\mu e^{-\mu v}\mathbb 1_{\{u \geq 0\}}\mathbb 1_{\{v \geq 0\}}dudv\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{v+z}\lambda e^{-\lambda u}\mu e^{-\mu v}du dv\\
&= \int_0^\infty\mu e^{-\mu v}(1-e^{-\lambda (v+z)})dv \\
&= \int_0^\infty\mu e^{-\mu v}dv - \frac{\mu e^{-\lambda z}}{\lambda + \mu}\int_0^\infty(\lambda+\mu) e^{-(\lambda+\mu) v}dv \\
&= 1 - \frac{\mu e^{-\lambda z}}{\lambda + \mu}.
\end{align}

This is not $1/2$ in general. For example, take $\lambda = 1$, $\mu =2 $.

Comment: First your example raises the question of the existence of two variables independent variables such that X-Y has a shifted exponential distribution. Is there any probability theorem that guarantees that ? And second I added some assumptions to my previous problem.

Comment: @Jan Van Impe, you just changed the question when you were given the negative answer. I'm not going to answer the changed question. I will edit my answer with explicit $X$ and $Y$, instead of $Z$.